# View web page source code on iOS

Tags: ios, applications, web-browsing, html

Is there a way for non-jailbroken iOS to view the source code for a web page? Does Apple's web API allow this?

Comment: There may also be HTML/CSS editors in the App store that will allow you to see the HTML source for any appropriate URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following as a bookmark. I call mine *View Source*. It will open up a new window with the HTML source.

```
javascript:(function()%7Bvar%20a=window.open(%22about:blank%22).document;a.write(%22%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Chtml%3E%3Chead%3E%3Ctitle%3ESource%20of%20%22+location.href+'%3C/title%3E%3Cmeta%20name=%22viewport%22%20content=%22width=device-width%22%20/%3E%3C/head%3E%3Cbody%3E%3C/body%3E%3C/html%3E');a.close();var%20b=a.body.appendChild(a.createElement(%22pre%22));b.style.overflow=%22auto%22;b.style.whiteSpace=%22pre-wrap%22;b.appendChild(a.createTextNode(document.documentElement.innerHTML))%7D)();
```

Comment: That works great, thank you! Is there any way I can get the text size to be a bit smaller?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write it and may javascript currently sucks.

Comment: Ah, OK then. I'll cope.